# What song plays at 7:38 of FMA Brotherhood episode 28?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

There is a really good song that either begins at or plays through 7:38, but I can't seem to find what the song is actually called. What song is this?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [Crisis in the North](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eWVoHVzhxg&list=PLE36689FDB43CE335)  of the second OST album of FMA brotherhood which is number 19 in the 2nd ost series composed by Masafumi Mima

Comment: It's actually track 19 on OST 2.

Comment: @Eric is it ;o My bad ill correct that